# Xcode 8.3 and min deployment target iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Correct me if I'm wrong but the only way to test if app supports iOS7 is to have real device with this system (i.e iPhone 4). On macOS Sierra developer is not able to run iOS 7 simulator.

Comment: Yes. To test it on iOS7, you need to test it on device. If you are able to install old xcode version like Xcode 5.0, you may run on simulator. Otherwise download simulators separately and add it in xcode environment

Answer (score 2):

To see the available simulators, go Xcode -> Window -> Devices -> click on `+` on the bottom left -> Add Simulator -> Choose `OS Version`

Here is the list of available simulators in Xcode 8.3.1:

[image]

8.1 is the earliest you can download.